# What container control is best suited to a repeating group of progress bars on a Windows Form?

Tags: winforms

I need to display one progress bar for each person in a dictionary of person-time pairs. The TableLayoutPanel seems a good bet for a container for my list of progress bars. Is it suitable, or what should I rather look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on how many 'person-time' pairs you have. Full `ProgressBars` I imaging will be fairly expensive if you have hundreds or thousands. You could overide the `DataGridViewCell/Column` and create a `DataGridViewProgressCell/Column`, this would be a lightweight solution, that also looks good...

[image: Progress]

If this is what you after I will post you some code. Otherwise, I would do as you have suggested, use a `TableLayoutPanel` seems a good-a-choice as any.

I hope this helps.

Comment: It's only about 10 bars, so maybe the grid is overkill for now. This is a very urgent project, so simplest is best, and that will probably be the TableLayoutPanel. Thanks!